# How can a make a list of numbers into a list of ranges by a certain value in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I need excel to make a list of numbers into a list of ranges with those numbers. In the image I need it so that the list of numbers 6-36 (start,end) get grouped by 6 (amount each person get) so it would be 6-11, 12-17, ect until it reaches 36. Those values can change. Im not sure if its possible, but I appreciate all the help I can get.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has the dynamic array formula SEQUENCE, put this in F2:

```
=SEQUENCE(C2,,A2,E2)&"-"&SEQUENCE(C2,,A2+E2-1,E2)
```

the results will spill down.

[image]

---

If not then put this in F2:

```
=IF(ROW($ZZ1)>$C$2,"",(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*$A$2+$A$2&"-"&(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*$A$2+$A$2+$E$2-1)
```

And copy down till you get blanks.

[image]

---

Note that since `6` is the first and they are grouped into 5 grouping, that `36` would be the start of the 6th grouping not the end of the 5th.